# How can I modify the default date-time format generated using sequelizeJS

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm looking to modify the `createdAt` column date-time format which is being generated by default using sequelize `Date`.

From Default Date-Time format: `2018-08-14T14:59:13.334Z` to this format: `14th August, 2018 2:59PM`

How can I achieve this?

**Migrations:**

```
createdAt: {
  allowNull: false,
  type: Sequelize.DATE
},
```

Comment: Is it an option for to store your dates in the DB as ISO (e.g. `2018-08-14T14:59:13.334Z`) but return them to the user in your preferred format?

Comment: @mcranston18 Yes, I mainly want to display in the prefered format. Format within DB doesn't matter.